# MVC 5 pass all listbox item to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, listbox

i am trying to pass my items in listbox back to controller.
My controller is always empty. If i declare another variable for it as List.It get pass back only the selected value. I want to pass back all the values.

i have 2 listbox which i use jquery to transfer the items between them.

```
$('#btnRight').click(function (e) {

    var selectedOpts = $('#CurrentRoles option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
        alert("Nothing to move.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#ListOfRoles').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {

    var selectedOpts = $('#ListOfRoles option:selected');

    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {

        alert("Nothing to move.");

        e.preventDefault();

    }

    $('#CurrentRoles').append($(selectedOpts).clone());

    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

here is my code for view

```
@Html.ListBox("CurrentRoles", new SelectList(Model.CurrentRoles, "Key", "Value"), new { id = "CurrentRoles" })

 public ActionResult Edit(UserRolesmanagement role,List<string> CurrentRoles)
{

   //logic
}
```

Model

```
public UserRolesmanagement() 
{
    user = new ApplicationUser();
    ListOfRoles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    CurrentRoles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    ListOfUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
}       

public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string,string> CurrentRoles { get; set;}
public List<IdentityRole> ListOfRoles { get; set; }
public List<ApplicationUser> ListOfUsers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually 1 input in your form data can transfer to controller just 1 value.
For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cons", "Report"))
{ 
    <input name="start" id="start" value="1234" />           
    <input name="end" id="end" value="2345" />
}
```

And controller:

```
public ActionResult Cons(string start, string end)
{
    //blahblahblah
}
```

So the simpest way for me if i want to transfer list of values is adding the input with all this values separated by commas. Something like this:

```
<input id="CurrentRolesValues" name="CurrentRolesValues" value="" style="display:none"/>
```

js for add values to input

```
var value="";
$('#ListOfRoles').children().each(function () {
    value+=$(this).val()+","
});
value=value.slice(0, -1); //delete last comma
$('#CurrentRolesValues').val(value);
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(UserRolesmanagement role, string CurrentRolesValues)
{
   List<string> roles = CurrentRolesValues.Split(',').ToList(); 
   //logic
}
```